# Compilation probleme

Tags: errors, packages, compiling

Hi I am using TeXmaker and I got this error during compilation

```
! LaTeX Error: File ccmap.sty not found.
```

Comment: @cfr -- a quick look at what google reports indicates that ccmap.sty is probably related to the thesis template for tsinghua university, so it might be available from some chinese site.  certainly french can be understood here by a lot more people than chinese.  but in any event, i'm not terribly optimistic that it will be familiar.

Comment: yes froù chinese sitehttp://iopscience.iop.org/journal/1674-1056/page/Guidelines-for-authors

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you correct my so-called translation? It is half guesswork and half the remnants of French from school. Since I dropped French and it has been a long time, I don't have much confidence. (You couldn't do 3 sciences and 3 languages to 16. I did 3 sciences and 2 languages, if you include Welsh.)

Comment: @moh We need code. An example. `\documentclass{??}\usepackage{??}\begin{document}??\end{document}` ??

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you think it is a typo for `cmap.sty`? Though you'd think they'd have had somebody complain in almost a decade, if so. But then, it is odd not to indicate where to find it as you'd think people would complain about that also.

Comment: \documentclass{cpbtex}

Comment: c'est le template de source qui fait ça

Comment: The class requires a package which is not standard. It cannot be used without that package. I do not know where to find that package. I have sent feedback to IoP asking them to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ccmap.sty` seems to be a chinese version of `cmap.sty`. It is required by the document class `cpbtex`.

You can download a zip archive with a LaTeX CPB template, `cpbtemplate.tex`, that contain both the `cptex` class and the missing `ccmap.sty` from this page: http://cpb.iphy.ac.cn/CN/column/item208.shtml

I had problems extracting the zip but I managed to get by. I made another archive for you in case you run into the same problem: https://goo.gl/TQ9uN3

I tested `cpbtemplate.tex`, it complains about fonts as I don't have chinese fonts installed. Other than that, it seems fine. Just make sure you have the file `ccmap.sty` in the same folder with your main tex file.